# Create a Timestamped ZIP Archive from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I've made a simple script to create a timestamped zip archive using a combination of PowerShell and a DOS command, but is there a better way to do this just using a single PowerShell command with piping?

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell get-date -format "{yyyymmdd-HHmmss}"`) DO (
SET ARCHTIMESTAMP=%%F
)

powershell Compress-Archive -Path yourpath -DestinationPath yourdestpath\yourname-%ARCHTIMESTAMP%.zip
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow kanine.   There certainly would be a simpler way to do that purely in PowerShell.   Is there some particular reason you want to do this using piping, or in a single command, or are you just looking for a cleaner way to express this?

Comment: Was just looking for a cleaner solution as it felt a bit clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incredibly close with what you have here. Just drop the `get-date` in where you're creating the string for your destination path.

```
Compress-Archive -Path yourpath -DestinationPath "yourdestpath\yourname-$(get-date -format "{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}").zip"
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help in a few other areas too!

Comment: I've made a small edit, the month placeholder is capital MM, lowercase mm is minutes.